# Is there a software that can put application software in 'hibernate'?

Tags: windows, utility

In an operating system like Windows, we can put the OS in hibernation so all the content in RAM is store in hard drive and be resume later. However, for application software it seems there is no such capability. If the computer is going to run out of RAM soon, I'll need to close some software to make way for the others. Otherwise the computer will become much slower when it use virtual RAM. If that software cannot save the existing configuration before exiting, I'll have to reopen all the files and windows after relaunching.

Although I don't know if this is technically feasible at all (since a software can involve a lot of process and file access lock), I would ask if there is software that can put other application software on 'hibernate' (i.e. to free up the RAM for other software) and let me decide when to resume it afterward.

Comment: Using the pagefile isnt' that much slow, as the system usually optimizes it access for idle periods. Another, simpler solution if you're critically low on RAM is to either upgrade RAM or find some alternative, ligher programs to what you're using right now. That said, I'm not aware of any software that effectively forces other arbitrary software out of memory, but highly doubt it can be done reliably.

Comment: From my understanding, it would have to be done at the operating system level. While Linux might allow of customs kernels, I do not believe that Windows does so. @Alejandro was correct - buy more RAM, or increase your swap file size, or run fewer programs